# UITableViewCell's attributes are nil when instantiating UITableView as a popover

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UISegmentedControl` from which I'd like to present a `UITableViewController` as a popover when I click on a `segmentedControl` segment. The issue I'm having is the moment I click on a segment, the popover starts to load, but crashes as myPopoverTableViewController loads. It crashes in

`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`, saying the attributes of my `PopoverTableViewCell` are `nil`.

For simplicity's sake, I'll reference my classes here:

```
myViewController: MyViewController
myPopoverTVController: PopoverTableViewController
myPopoverTVCell: PopoverTableViewCell
```

In `lldb`, I checked for the values of the cell, the `dataSource`, and it seems the only thing that's nil are the the attributes of `myPopoverTVCell`, which I register in `myPopoverTVController's viewWillAppear` with the following line:

```
tableView.register(PopoverTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

`myPopoverTVController` is not connected via a popover segue (though I've tried that) to `myViewController`. I've checked that I have `PopoverTableViewCell` referenced in the class for `myPopoverTVController's` prototype cell. I've double checked the connections from the cell to to the `PopoverTableViewCell` class. I checked that I've got the Table View Cell's identifier set to `cell` on the storyboard.

Here's how I begin the popover from `myViewController`, following [Apple's code](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller):

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    // instantiate the PopoverTableViewController
    let popoverTVC = PopoverTableViewController()
    // set variables on it
    popoverTVC.selectedSegmentIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
    popoverTVC.currentRegion = currentRegion
    // disignate presentation style as a popover
    popoverTVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

    present(popoverTVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let presentationController = UIPopoverPresentationController(presentedViewController: popoverTVC, presenting: self)
    presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = .up
    presentationController.sourceView = view
    presentationController.sourceRect = segmentedControl.frame
}
```

On `myPopoverTVController`, here's what my `cellForRowAt indexPath` looks like:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PopoverTableViewCell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! PopoverTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    switch selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0, 1:
        cell.areaLabel.text = popoverStringArray[indexPath.row]

    case 2:
        let countryList = locationManager.countryList
        let countryCodes = locationManager.countryCodes

        cell.areaLabel?.text = countryList[indexPath.row]
        cell.flagLabel?.text = countryCodes[indexPath.row]

    default:
        break
    }

    return cell
}
```

I checked the variables that are set upon instantiation on `myViewController` and they've all got values. It's just the `tableViewCell` attributes that are `nil`--`lldb` returns a memory address for the cell when I type `po cell`. I've set up `UITableViews` a million times, but I can't figure this thing out. Any suggestions re: what I'm doing wrong are greatly appreciated. I'll rest assured my problem is a startlingly silly omission on my part. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Do you have a cell with reuse identifier 'cell' with class PopoverTableViewCell ? Check the reuse identifier once.

Comment: Yes, that was one of the first things I checked. I am nearly certain it's got something to do with the popover's instantiation, as I've configured TVC's many times.

Comment: Try to instantiate your PopoverTableViewController object like this 'let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController") as! PopoverTableViewController

Comment: Ugh! Same crash at the same spot. There's a memory address for the cell, but the label attributes are `nil`

Comment: @Rajat  I found a different way to skin the cat and cleaned out a bunch of code, too. Thank you for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw in the towel trying to use Apple's code and figured out an alternative method to get the popover to work.

I `ctrl+dragged` in storyboard from my `myViewController` to `myPopoverTVController`. I set the **segue identifier** to `popoverSegue` and set it to display as a popover. I also specified an anchor point.

From there, I gutted the code in `segmentedControlAction()` to replaced it with the following:

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "popoverSegue", sender: segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)

}
```

I added the following code to my `prepareForSegue` on `myViewController`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "popoverSegue" {
        let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! PopoverTableViewController
        destinationViewController.selectedSegmentIndex = sender as! Int
        destinationViewController.currentRegion = currentRegion


        let popoverController = destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController

        if popoverController != nil {
            popoverController?.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

I also added a delegate method to `myViewController` with an extension:

```
extension MyViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }
}
```

Lastly, I took out a local reference to the data source in `myPopoverTVController` so it now looks like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PopoverTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    switch selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        cell.areaLabel.text = locationManager.cityList(geographicRegion: currentRegion!)[indexPath.row]
        cell.flagLabel.isHidden = true

    case  1:
        cell.areaLabel.text = locationManager.stateList(geographicRegion: currentRegion!)[indexPath.row]
        cell.flagLabel.isHidden = true

    case 2:
        cell.areaLabel?.text = locationManager.countryList[indexPath.row]
        cell.flagLabel?.text = locationManager.countryCodes[indexPath.row].flag()

    default:
        break
    }

    return cell
}
```

...and it worked.

The End ;)